# Efficient bitwise reverse of the successor

Tags: c++, performance, bit-manipulation

The most efficient way I've found to bitwise-reverse an integral type is this:

```
template <class NT = std::size_t>
NT reverseBits(NT num)
{
  NT count = sizeof(num) * 8 - 1;
  NT reverse_num = num;
  num >>= 1;
  while(num) {
     reverse_num <<= 1;
     reverse_num |= num & 1;
     num >>= 1;
     count--;
  }
  reverse_num <<= count;
  return reverse_num;
}
```

But given some integer `I` and that I already have the result  `rI = reverseBits(I)`:

Is there a way to obtain `reverseBits(I+1)` directly from `rI` without actually calling `reverseBits` (or something with equivalent complexity) again?

Comment: Just a quick question about the scope.  Generally when you are inverting bit order it is done for purposes of endianness. In which case it is done eight bits at a time which would greatly simplify your code.  Are you trying to swap the entire integer or by byte?

Comment: @mreff555 the entire integer

Comment: In that case, that is roughly how I would do it.

Comment: If you have `countr_one` or equivalent, you can determine exactly how many bits are flipped by adding 1, compute a mask of the same number of bits on the left, and xor.

Comment: That site has many tricks with bits in C: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html. One way, for 8 bits abcdefgh, you would swap abcd with efgh, then abef with cdgh, then aceg with bdfh using mask and shift. Thus you can have O(log N) instead of O(n) for reversing bits.

Comment: Do you also have `I`? There is a good trick to use if you have *both* `I` and its reverse, to increment the reverse by XORing it by something.

Comment: Would like to avoid keep an extra copy of the unreversed `I` @harold but nonetheless sounds like an interesting trick to know!

Comment: @Phil1970 that `5 log(N)` sounds like a winner

Comment: If you had `I`, and `rI`, then let `M = I ^ (I + 1)` and `next_rI = rI ^ (M << lzcnt(M))`. Nate's trick avoids having `I` around, but it's more difficult to create the mask in that trick.

Comment: @harold, I don't understand any of this modular/arithmetic math. In fact I was trying to think about this problem on basis other than 2 and I realised I have no idea how the xor operator looks in non-binary mantissa. Do you have an intuitive way of understanding how/why this works on base 2?

Comment: `I ^ (I + 1)` basically means "give me all the bits that changed between `I` and its successor". That mask will always be contiguous, the digits that flipped from 1 to 0 by carrying and finally a 0 that flipped to a 1 and "stopped" the carry. A contiguous mask like that is easy to reverse, namely by shifting it left until its leftmost 1 is aligned with the most significant bit, which is what `M << lzcnt(M)` does (calculate how many zeroes there are above the mask, then shift by that amount, so it goes all the way left)

Comment: @harold, I was referring to the https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel `5 log(N)` algorithm, it seems bewildering that would turn out the same result as bit per bit inverting. I ran that and in fact they return the same result. But I'm not sure how to prove that result

Comment: @Phil1970 since the size of an integer is fixed, it's `O(1)` regardless.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I am talking about the number of operations related to the number of bits to reverse. Thus O(1) would be if you have a CPU instruction for that in that context.

Comment: @Phil1970 no, that's not what O(1) means. Number of instructions to be executed depend on the number of bits inside the integer, which has an upper bound (64 bits, etc).

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili you're not wrong, but then how else would you express the difference between an algorithm that takes a number of steps proportional to log(bits) and an algorithm that always takes a fixed number of steps?

Comment: @harold you can say it's more efficient but that needs to be backed up with profiling data.

Comment: We can say the same thing for any algorithm about the need of programming if data has a finite size which in the majority of application this is the case. That why, it is often recommended to use `std::vector` by default. Neverthless, in that case with large integer type (64 or even 128 bits), one does not need profiling to know which algorithm is faster (assuming the compiler does not recognize the pattern) as obviously 6 or 7 swaps would be faster that 32 or 64 swaps respectively...

Comment: **need of profiling** in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it this way:

- How would I implement `I+1` if I had to implement it manually?
- How can I "mirror" above implementation to compute `r(I+1)` from `rI`?

Incrementing a number by `1` can be done as follows:

1. Look for the rightmost (nearest to the LSB) `0`.
2. Change that `0` to `1`.
3. Set everything to the right to `0`.

Now lets mirror this approach:

1. Look for the **leftmost** (nearest to the MSB) `0`.
2. Change that `0` to `1`.
3. Set everything to the **left** to `0`.

Here is a basic implementation for `unsigned int`s.

```
// sets all bits except for leading zeroes
// example 0001010011 => 0001111111
unsigned int mask_leading_zeroes(unsigned int n) {
  // assumes that int is at most 64 bits wide
  n |= n >> 1;
  n |= n >> 2;
  n |= n >> 4;
  n |= n >> 8;
  n |= n >> 16;
  n |= n >> 32;
  return n;
}

int main() {
  unsigned int rI = 12345;
  unsigned int mask = mask_leading_zeroes(~rI);
  unsigned int rI1 = (mask ^ (mask >> 1)) | (rI & mask);
}
```

There are many ways for implementing `mask_leading_zeroes`. Here is an alternative, less specialized implementation which should also work with any other unsigned type, but is probably slower.

```
unsigned int mask_leading_zeroes(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int shift = 1;
    unsigned int old;
    do {
        old = n;
        n |= n >> shift;
        shift <<= 1;
    } while (old != n);
    return -n;
}
```

You could also think about using functions like `__builtin_ffs` to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

For completitude, this is the templated c++17 version using the [suggestion in the comments](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel), with partial specializations for 4-byte and 8-byte words

```
#include <climits>
#include <type_traits>
// source: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel
template <class NT = std::size_t, std::enable_if_t< (sizeof(NT) > 8), int > = 0>
NT uFastBitReverse(NT v) {
  unsigned int s = sizeof(v) * CHAR_BIT; // bit size; must be power of 2
  NT mask = ~0;
  while ((s >>= 1) > 0)
  {
    mask ^= (mask << s);
    v = ((v >> s) & mask) | ((v << s) & ~mask);
  }
  return v;
};

// source: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel
template <class NT, std::enable_if_t< sizeof(NT) == 4, int > = 0 >
NT uFastBitReverse(NT v) {
  //std::cout << " in the 4 byte specialization " << std::endl;
    v = ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555) | ((v & 0x55555555) << 1);
    v = ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333) | ((v & 0x33333333) << 2);
    v = ((v >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F) | ((v & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4);
    v = ((v >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF) | ((v & 0x00FF00FF) << 8);
    v = ( v >> 16             ) | ( v               << 16);
    return v;
};

template <class NT, std::enable_if_t< sizeof(NT) == 8, int > = 0 >
NT uFastBitReverse(NT v) {
  //std::cout << " in the 8 byte specialization " << std::endl;
    v = ((v >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555) | ((v & 0x5555555555555555) << 1);
    v = ((v >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333) | ((v & 0x3333333333333333) << 2);
    v = ((v >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) | ((v & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) << 4);
    v = ((v >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) | ((v & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8);
    v = ((v >> 16)& 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) | ((v & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16);
    v = ( v >> 32                     ) | ( v                       << 32);
    return v;
};
```